# Why Camera.Parameters.setFocusAreas Not Working with some Android Devices?

Tags: android, camera

i'm trying to make an app that uses Camera and trying to enable autoFocus when the user touch the Camera preview .

i used this method to enable onTouch focus .

```
private boolean cameraFocus(MotionEvent event, @NonNull CameraSource cameraSource, @NonNull String focusMode) {
    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();


    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

    float touchMajor = event.getTouchMajor();
    float touchMinor = event.getTouchMinor();

    Rect touchRect = new Rect((int)(x - touchMajor / 2), (int)(y - touchMinor / 2), (int)(x + touchMajor / 2), (int)(y + touchMinor / 2));

    Rect focusArea = new Rect();

    focusArea.set(touchRect.left * 2000 / cameraView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.top * 2000 / cameraView.getHeight() - 1000,
            touchRect.right * 2000 / cameraView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.bottom * 2000 / cameraView.getHeight() - 1000);

    // Submit focus area to camera

    ArrayList<Camera.Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
    focusAreas.add(new Camera.Area(focusArea, 1000));

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFocusMode(focusMode);
                    params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                    // Start the autofocus operation

                    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
                            // currently set to auto-focus on single touch
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }



    return false;
}
```

it's working fine with most Samsung Devices .

but when i test it on any Huawei phone , it doesn't work and crashes.

**the good thing is that it works great on Huawei if i don't use** :

```
params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
```

**here's the error log:**

```
 Huawei Honor 5X (HNKIW-Q), 2048MB RAM, Android 6.0

java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters (Native Method)

  at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters (Camera.java:2260)

  at MY_PACKAGE_NAME.ReadingActivity.cameraFocus (ReadingActivity.java:329)

  at MY_PACKAGE_NAME.ReadingActivity.access$800 (ReadingActivity.java:32)

  at MY_PACKAGE_NAME.ReadingActivity$3.onTouch (ReadingActivity.java:281)

  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:9384)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2555)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2197)

  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2461)

  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1777)

  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:2865)

  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)

  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2422)

  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:9610)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4447)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4313)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3847)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3900)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3866)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3992)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3874)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4049)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3847)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3900)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3866)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3874)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3847)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6146)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:6120)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6081)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6262)

  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:192)

  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)

  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:330)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5621)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:794)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

**i'm trying to figure out why is this happening with some Devices and to fix it?**

Comment: Post error log.

Comment: i just did what you ask me for, by the way : lines: ReadingActivity.java:329 and 32 are where my camerafocus method at.